# Can Excel Multiply Multiple Numbers with one formula?

Tags: excel

I am looking for a formula that works like sum but instead of summarysing each element I want it to multiple each lement.

For eaxample if I have the following dataset A1=1,A2=2,A3=3,A4=4 the FORMULA(A1:A4) would do the following 1*2*3*4  = 24

Is there such formula?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PRODUCT(A1:A4)` is the function you need.